# Unable binding from class on C#

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8.1

Here is code of class:

```
  public class listboxitem
    {
        public string textmenu { get; set; }
        public string logomenu { get; set; }
    }
```

But when im binding it on textbox that's not show...

I have these array:

```
 private string[] Logo_menu_array = { "/Assets/star-6-48.ico", "/Assets/note-48.ico", "/Assets/note-48.ico", "medal-48.ico", "joystick-48.ico" };

 private string[] Text_menu_array={"Phổ biến trên YouTuBe","Âm nhạc","Thể thao","Trò chơi"};  

 //load menu
    public void Load_Menu()
    {
        List<listboxitem> text = new List<listboxitem>();
        listboxitem items=new listboxitem();
        for(int i=0;i<Text_menu_array.Length&& i<Logo_menu_array.Length;i++)
        {
            items.textmenu=i.ToString();
        }
        for(int j=0;j<Logo_menu_array.Length;j++)
        {
            items.logomenu = j.ToString();
        }
        text.Add(items);
    }
```

This website didn't agreed show more code. Ready hard to ask these my question.
I added code:

```
 <ListBox Name="lst_menu" Foreground="Red">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="{Binding logomenu}"></Image>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding textmenu}"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

And here to loaded:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //get menu
       List<listboxitem> menu_list = new List<listboxitem>();
       Load_Menu();
       lst_menu.ItemsSource = menu_list;


    }
```

Comment: I don't see any binding code here

Comment: <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding logomenu}"></Image>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding textmenu}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                              
                            </DataTemplate>

Comment: Lisbox name="lstmenu"
Code: lstmenu

  public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //get menu
            List<listboxitem> menu_list = new List<listboxitem>();
           //Load_Menu();
           lst_menu.ItemsSource = menu_list;
           
            
        }

Comment: It just seems like your not setting the correct List<T> as your ItemSource, In Load_Menu you add to a Collection named "text" and in your Main() you apply some Collecion named "menu_list" , by the way have i complimented you on your naming decisions yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here...

Firstly, we need to see the XAML to see how you are binding this in your UI. I'm going to assume you have something like:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

Then a template that presents these.

In your code you have a List object called text which exists only in your method. You need to assign this value to a property in your view model onto which you can bind - based on the above:

```
public List<ListItem> Items {get;set;}
```

This property should trigger PropertyChanged as defined in INotifyPropertyChanged so implement that on your class. [Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx)

That gets you the basics. If you want to dynamically control this collection - i.e. change items at runtime - you should investigate ObservableCollection.

**EDIT:**
Based upon your full code listing, using code behind. You are setting your lst_menu.ItemsSource to an empty List. Your Load_Menu() builds a collection but does not return it.

```
public List<listboxitem> Load_Menu()
{
    List<listboxitem> text = new List<listboxitem>();
    listboxitem items=new listboxitem();
    for(int i=0;i<Text_menu_array.Length&& i<Logo_menu_array.Length;i++)
    {
        items.textmenu=i.ToString();
    }
    for(int j=0;j<Logo_menu_array.Length;j++)
    {
        items.logomenu = j.ToString();
    }
    text.Add(items);
    return text;
    // Note you will only ever return one item here - check the logic
}
```

Then in your constructor:

```
   List<listboxitem> menu_list = Load_Menu();
   lst_menu.ItemsSource = menu_list;
```

Assuming you want the arrays to be used to build your collection, try using the following for build menu:

```
List<listboxitem> text = new List<listboxitem>();
for(int i =0; i< Math.Min(Logo_menu_array.Length, Text_menu_array.Length, i++)
{
    var l = new listboxitem();
    l.logomenu = Logo_menu_array[i];
    l.textmenu = Logo_menu_array[i];
}
return text;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I has answers @rohit vats on your line. Because stack.. don't upload more code.

Comment: Sorry - that makes no sense at all. Follow the directions I've suggested, if it helps you then mark it as the answer. If not, try and edit your question to include your code with better formatting. So we can figure out what the issue you're having is.