# select listViewItems in listView as text

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, multipleselection

In ListView there are 3 option of SelectionMode
1.Single - only one item can be selected.
2.Multiple - you can select muliple items, one after the other.
3.Extended - You can select multiple items and used Ctrl or Shift key.

I'm need to select some items in ListView as text in TextBox. 
i.e. press with the left button of mouse, until the mouse is up.
and mark all between items as Selected.

How can I make it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.Single: SelectionMode="Single"?

2 Mutiple : i think use binding
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133244/unable-binding-from-class-on-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment39133896_25133244)

3 
[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.multiselect.aspx)

Or You try this line  SelectionMode="Muti..."

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the porpose of this problem is to display listView of TextBlocks for allow use ItemsSource of ListView for display text for several reasone.
behind each textBlock that contains a word, there are in the ViewModel class named Word. that contains the text of the word and property of IsSelected.

I solve this problem, by adding 3 EventSetter event to the ListViewItem,

1.PreviewMouseLeftDown

2.MouseEnter

3.PreviewMouseLeftUp

and adding a flag of IsInSelection, and two object Word that present the control in the view,1.firstSelectionWord, 2.lastSelectionWord.

and, when the first event raise, i update the current control to be Selected.
and set a flag IsInSelection to true. and set firstSelectionWord = lastSelectionWord = current word pressed.

in the MouseEnter event i checked if  IsInSelection is true, and them mark also the current control to Selected=true. set the lastSelectionWord = current word pressed.

and call a method that mark all the Word between them as selected.

in the PreviewMouseLeftUp function, i set the IsInSelection = false.